Sharing team members performance with peers
I lead a team of engineers, and senior management have asked us to prepare a presentation on the performance and potential of each of our team members.
We're being asked to add this to a powerpoint and share it infront of the other technical leads in our product group, plus senior management.
I'm not particularly comfortable doing this because it feels a bit dehumanising, but particularly because we're being asked to share it infront of other tech leads- I don't think we should talk about people's performance infront of people that aren't above them in the heirachy.
Is my viewpoint reasonable, and should I push back, or should I just accept this and fill out the powerpoint?

To be clear, are you being asked to talk about the performance and potential of the team as a whole or the individuals on a team? It seems like you're at least interpreting the request to be about individual performance, but it's not clear if that's the intent of the request.

Thanks, modified the question to reflect you comment

Just to clarify, are those peers their peers, or are they your peers, so hierarchically above them, just not in a straight line?

What is your jurisdiction? In some jurisdictions, this would be straight-up illegal. Confer with your lawyer / ombudsman / Betriebsrat / union rep / whichever applies to you before even thinking about this! (I was once asked to prepare a similar report by my line manager, who was in a different jurisdiction than me. Shortly afterwards, I got a panicked call, telling me to forget the whole thing – turns out, all line managers had been asked by the leadership to do this … including the legal department and members of the Betriebsrat.

They're my peers, so they're n+1 the people being discussed


should I push back, or should I just accept this and fill out the powerpoint?

That depends a bit on WHY they want to do it and what the purpose of the exercise is. There are valid reasons: Some companies use "forced ranking" as a performance metric. If you have a round of layoffs coming up or some extra money or bonusses to spread around, you may have to make a ranked list over all departments. Often of these is not fun or pleasant but it can be justifiable.
Despite being awkward this can be a helpful exercise. You learn about the strengths and weaknesses of other teams that your people may interact with and that's helpful in determining best project assignments and gives context when dealing with potential team issues.  It can also help creating a promotion strategy across the department.
In any case first you need to understand the REASON for the presentation. You can push back if you can present valid and well thought out business reasons as counter arguments. "I don't like it", is not going to cut it.

Include only positive information.
Simply put, use this as an opportunity to promote your team members by telling the other managers how awesome they are. If one of them did some cool or important thing, let them know about it. If they contributed to solving a problem, let them know! If they improved a business metric, tell them about it! If the team as a whole performed well, talk about that too.
If management staff doesn't have visibility of your teams' achievements, they'll never get the credit they deserve for their work.

Ask for clarification.
It isn't unreasonable to understand productivity and capabilities of team members.
A good example is:
If a new project is being planned, wouldn't the next level up want to know which team(s) to give it to based on abilities? Or where to give budget for new hires to fill in gaps? If you don't have a strong DBA on your team, wouldn't that be a good use of budget?
There is a blatant assumption that businesses just want to stomp their employees into mush. That isn't how a company can grow long-term.
If your company's goal is to stomp your team members into mush, well - then that is a whole different story. Who would put up with that if they can find a better job.
What do you think your company's goal is?

I would just put in something generic.
If asked I would say I don't have complete performance metrics to use as it's not part of my role to collect that information or perform such analysis.
